# Ajax dependable drop down list issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have two drop down list in my webpage and one is dependent on the other. The Ajax code i am using is working fine in Chrome, Mozilla but not in IE (i am using IE9). Can someone please help me in getting this corrected.

This is the Ajax code-

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
  var xmlHttp  
  var xmlHttp

  function showSubCategory(str){
      if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
      xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else if (window.ActiveXObject){
      xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      if (xmlHttp==null){
      alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
      return;
      } 
      var url="jsp/subcategory.jsp";
      url +="?count=" +str;
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange1;
      xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
      }

      function stateChange1(){   
      if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
      document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
      }   
      }
```

This the main jsp page where the drop down lists are.--

```
 <table>
     <tr>
<td align="right" width="10%">Category </td>
<td>
   <select id='category' name="adv.categoryNo" onchange="showSubCategory(this.value)">  
       <option >Select the Category</option>  
     <%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","user","pwd");  
Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("Select * from categories");
while(rs1.next()){
    %>
    <option value="<%=rs1.getString(2)%>"><%=rs1.getString(2)%></option>  
    <%
}
    %>
    </select>                                  
     </td>
    </tr>

   Second drop down list 


    <tr>
      <td align="right" width="10%">Subcategory <span class="mandatory">*</span>: </td>
       <td>
         <div id='subcategory'>  
         <select id='subcat'  name='subcategory'>  
         <option >Select the Subcategory</option>  
         </select>  
         </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is the **subcategory** jsp file which is called by Ajax.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
 <%
  String category=request.getParameter("count");  
   String buffer="<select name='adv.subCategoryNo'><option >Select the Subcategory</option>";  
 try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","user","pwd");  
  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from subcategories where     categoryName='"+category+"' ");  
   while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(3)+"'>"+rs.getString(3)+"</option>";  
   }  
    buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
    response.getWriter().println(buffer); 
    }
   catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }
   %>
```

Strange thing is if i change the **getElementById** param in the following function of the Ajax code from "**subcat**" to "**subcategory**" which is the div id covering the second drop down list, it works fine in IE and other browsers.

```
function stateChange1(){   
      if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
      document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
      }
```

If i follow the above approach i am not able to do any javascript form validation for that Subcategory select box using the following JS code.

```
 function madeSelectionCity(){
  var subcat = document.getElementById('subcat');
if(subcat.value == "Select the City name"){
    alert("Please select a subcategory first");
    subcat.focus();
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
 }
```

Hope i am clear in my question. Please let me know if any more explanation is required. Thanks

Comment: can you post the **responseText** of the **XMLHttpRequest** object.

Comment: please let me know whether my answer works or not.

Comment: i have edited my answer. Please take look at it. Answer to your first comment is yes, change the html code , it should work.

Comment: 'buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
response.setContentType("text/html") ;    response.getWriter().println(buffer);'

Comment: By clicking the 'right'(which turns green when clicked) mark on the left side of my answer you have already accepted my answer and marked it as solved. Apart from this you can also vote-up my answer by clicking on the up-arrow above 0(left side of my answer)

Comment: can you please give me ur email-id so that i can explain you the bug in your application. I cannot mention entire eplantion here.Thank You

Comment: Hi ravi, here is my email id- bhaskars4u@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the below line of code( in **subcategory.jsp** called by **ajax** code)

```
 String buffer="<select name='adv.subCategoryNo'><option >Select the Subcategory</option>";
```

to

```
 String buffer="<select id='subcat' name='adv.subCategoryNo'><option >Select the Subcategory</option>";
```

and also add this line of code ( in **subcategory.jsp** called by **ajax** code)

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

on the webpage(main page) , the html should be

```
 <div id='subcategory'>
 </div>
```

and ajax(main page) code should be

```
function stateChange1(){   
      if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
      document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
      }
```

Comment: You mean, i should change this code on my main jsp-

     <div id='subcategory'>            
      <select id='subcat'  name='subcategory'>            
       <option >Select the Subcategory</option></select>           </div> 

to just- <div id='subcategory'>  </div> 

Then what will happen to the Select list? How ill it be displayed in the page?

Comment: And can you please tell me where i should add this line exactly--- response.setContentType("text/html");

Comment: Thanks Ravi for your quick response. But i am at my workplace right now where i dont have the access to my project. I will implement your answer and will surely  let you know. Thanks much.

Comment: Hi Ravi... It worked. Thank you so much for your help. When i put just <div id='subcategory'> </div> , initially the second select box does not show up. It appears only when a option is selected in the first drop down list. So i changed it to--- <div id='subcategory'> <select>  
  <option >Select the Subcategory</option>  
</select>  
</div>..

It is now working perfectly. Can you please explain what was the issue here? I am accepting your answer.

Comment: How to accept this answer and mark this question as solved here? I am new to stackoverflow...